# google maps api v3 hide a specific marker on button click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on aps.net MVC 5, I am using **Google Maps Api V3** in my project

Also, i am using **dot net Highcharts** to view my data in charts

There is a search functionality which is placed in a partial view and then it is rendering in another view

The map is in my Layout which is passed in my View where the search partial view is rendering

See the bellow image

[image]

Now, i want is whenever i select a serial number and after filling start and end date on **show chart** click the specific marker on the map will be visible only and all the other markers are hidden

Bellow is my search controller code

```
public ActionResult MultiGraph(string search, string start_date, string End_date, int? page)
    {//  search = "11111111";
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var dtt = db.ADS_Device_Data.Select(a => a.Device_Serial_Number).Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var item in dtt)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item, Value = item });
            }
        }
        ViewBag.search = items;
....... all other code for chart is placed here also 
}
```

Bellow is my Partial View of search

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MultiGraph", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="form-inline">
        @Html.DropDownList("search", null, "Select Serial Number", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:20%" })

        <input type='text' name="start_date" id="startTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" autocomplete="off" />
        <input type='text' name="End_date" id="endTime" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date" autocomplete="off" />
        <input id="recall" type="submit" value="Show Chart" class="btn btn-success" autocomplete="off"/>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">
            <img src="~/Image/back-button.png" alt="Go Back" title="Go Back" >

        </a>
        @*<input type="button" value="Back" class="btn btn-success" onclick="@Html.ActionLink("Index","Home")"/>*@
        @*<button class="btn btn-success form-control" onclick="" name="Back" value="Back"></button>*@
    </div>}
```

It's rendering in `MultiGraph.cshtml` view

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MLayout.cshtml";
<p>
<div style="font-family:'Times New Roman' ; font-size:large" align="center">

    @Html.Partial("_Search")

</div>
```

In above code `_MLayout.cshtml` is the layout for my charts

Bellow is my `_MLayout` code for chart

```
<div id="map" style="width: 320px; height: 350px; margin-top:-10px"></div>
```

Bellow is the script for map

```
<script>
//Map initialization
// Define your locations: HTML content for the info window, latitude, longitude
var locations =
[
    ['<h4>Meter# 11111111<h4>', 31.27045, 74.17811],
    ['<h4>Meter# 22222222<h4>', 31.26972, 74.17855],
    ['<h4>Meter# 33333333<h4>', 31.27081, 74.17964],
    ['<h4>Meter# 44444444<h4>', 31.27007, 74.18037],
    ['<h4>Meter# 55555555<h4>', 31.26956, 74.18123],
];

// Info Window Content
var infoWindowContent =
[

    //1
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
     '<h4>Meter# 11111111</h4>' +
     '<h4><b>Description</b></h4>' +
     '<p>Accurate Pvt Ltd </br>GSM Energy Meter</p>' +
     '<h4><b>Coordinates:</b></h4>' +
     '<p>31.27045, 74.17811</p>' + '</div>'
    ],
    //2
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
     '<h4>Meter# 22222222</h4>' +
     '<h4><b>Description</b></h4>' +
     '<p>Accurate Pvt Ltd </br>GSM Energy Meter</p>' +
     '<h4><b>Coordinates:</b></h4s>' +
     '<p>31.26972, 74.17855</p>' + '</div>'
    ],
    //3
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
     '<h4>Meter# 33333333</h4>' +
     '<h4><b>Description</b></h4>' +
     '<p>Accurate Pvt Ltd </br>GSM Energy Meter</p>' +
     '<h4><b>Coordinates:</b></h4>' +
     '<p>31.27081, 74.17964</p>' + '</div>'
    ],
    //4
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
     '<h4>Meter# 44444444</h4>' +
     '<h4><b>Description</b></h4>' +
     '<p>Accurate Pvt Ltd </br>GSM Energy Meter</p>' +
     '<h4><b>Coordinates:</b></h4>' +
     '<p>31.27007, 74.18037</p>' + '</div>'
    ],
     //5
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
     '<h4>Meter# 55555555</h4>' +
     '<h4><b>Description</b></h4>' +
     '<p>Accurate Pvt Ltd </br>GSM Energy Meter</p>' +
     '<h4><b>Coordinates:</b></h4>' +
     '<p>31.26956, 74.18123</p>' + '</div>'
    ],
];



// Setup the different icons and shadows
var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';

var icons = [
  iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
  //iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
  //iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
]

var iconsLength = icons.length;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.27016, 74.17932),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    //content: 'Power Monitoring Solutions',
    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
    }
});

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


var markers = new Array();

var iconCounter = 0;

// Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: icons[iconCounter]
    });
    iconCounter++;

    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
        infoWindow.close();
        autoCenter();
        //center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.27016, 74.17932)
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(window, "click", function (event) {
        infoWindow.close();
        autoCenter();
        //center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.27016, 74.17932)
    });


    //google.maps.event.addListener(locations, 'mouseover', function () {
    //    locations.open(map, this);
    //});

    //google.maps.event.addListener(locations, 'mouseout', function () {
    //    locations.close();
    //});

    // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
    if (iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
        iconCounter = 0;
    }
}

function autoCenter() {
    //  Create a new viewpoint bound
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    //  Go through each...
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
    }
    //  Fit these bounds to the map
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
autoCenter();

</script>
```

How to do this i have no idea at all

**Updated code**

I have added this piece of code into my script

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: icons[iconCounter],
        serialNumber: locations[i][3],
    });
    iconCounter++;

    var serialNumber = search;   

    // loop through all the markers
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].serialNumber != serialNumber) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        } else {
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
        }
    }
```

On 1st run i am getting bellow map

[image]

This marker is for serial number `55555555`

Also for `55555555` serial number the info window is not showing

For now it's ok to have an empty map on first run but still this yellow marker is showing

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Is the 'serial number' like the `Meter# 11111111` you're adding to the infowindows?

Comment: Yes i am but at search i am only number like '11111111'

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is have some way of identifying each marker by its ID / serial number, the `1111111` part.  Ideally you'd amend your `locations` array to have that as its own value, or you could use a regex to parse it from the first value. Then you can add that as a property to each marker, which you can check later.  e.g. something like this:

```
var locations = [
    ['<h4>Meter# 11111111<h4>', 31.27045, 74.17811, 11111111],
    ['<h4>Meter# 22222222<h4>', 31.26972, 74.17855, 22222222],
    ['<h4>Meter# 33333333<h4>', 31.27081, 74.17964, 33333333],
    ['<h4>Meter# 44444444<h4>', 31.27007, 74.18037, 44444444],
    ['<h4>Meter# 55555555<h4>', 31.26956, 74.18123, 55555555]
];

// Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: icons[iconCounter],
        serialNumber: locations[i][3]
    });
```

Then when you submit the form, have a javascript event listener which gets the value entered by the user, and sees if you have a marker with that ID, e.g.

```
var serialNumber = // whatever the user entered

// loop through all the markers
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i].serialNumber != serialNumber) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }  else {
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
    }
}
```

Comment: @ducan  
I have accessed the serial number using session variable var search = '@Session["search"]'; alert(search); and it's displaying correct serial number , as per your solution it's looking good + i also want to show the info window of that serial number's marker

Comment: You already have an event listener for when you click the marker to open its infowindow, so all you need to do is trigger the click on the correct marker. I've updated my answer to do that.

Comment: It's working but i don't want markers to be hidden on 1st run i want them to be visible on 1st run then after selecting serial number i want markers to hide else the matched serial number

Comment: "when you submit the form, have a javascript event listener "

Comment: My form is submitting in a partial view and map is in layout

Comment: Sorry, I'm not doing all your work for you.  Your ASP code like `@using (Html.BeginForm("MultiGraph", "Home", FormMethod.Get))` is meaningless to me, I'd need to see the rendered HTML.  But the javascript required for this last part (adding an event listener on submit of the form) is trivially easy: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Comment: @ducan: i am really thankful to you, as far as now it's ok to view an empty map on 1st run but there is a problem can you please see my updated code